# Find a function with cycles of every length

Tags: code-golf, math, number, permutations

A function is said to have a *cycle of length n* if there exists an *x* in its domain such that *f<sup>n</sup>(x) = x* and *f<sup>m</sup>(x) ≠ x* for *0 < m < n*, where the superscript *n* denotes *n*-fold application of *f*. Note that a cycle of length *1* is a fixed point *f(x) = x*.

Your task is to implement a [*bijective* function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) from the integers to themselves, which has exactly one cycle of every positive length *n*. A bijective function is a one-to-one correspondence, i.e. every integer mapped to exactly once. Having exactly one cycle of length *n* means that there are exactly *n* distinct numbers *x* for which *f<sup>n</sup>(x) = x* and *f<sup>m</sup>(x) ≠ x* for *0 < m < n*.

Here is an example of what such a function might look like around *x = 0*:

```
x     ... -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 ...
f(x)  ...  2  4  6 -3 -1  1 -4  0 -2  5  7 -7 -6  3 -5 ...
```

This excerpt contains cycles of length *1* to *5*:

```
n   cycle
1    0
2   -2  1
3   -4 -3 -1
4   -5  6  3  7
5   -7  2  5 -6  4
...
```

Note that above I'm using "function" only in the mathematical sense. You may write either a function or a full program in your language of choice, as long as it takes a single (signed) integer as input and returns a single (signed) integer. As usual you may take input via STDIN, command-line argument, function argument etc. and output via STDOUT, function return value or function (out) argument etc.

Of course, many languages don't (easily) support arbitrary-precision integers. It's fine if your implementation only works on the range of your language's native integer type, as long as that covers at least the range *[-127, 127]* and that it would work for arbitrary integers if the language's integer type was replaced with arbitrary-precision integers.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

Comment: [Closely related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53642/8478) While the differences seem minor, they imply that none of the old approaches work without significant modification, and in particular I don't think the winning approach from that challenge can be adapted at all.

Comment: "has exactly one cycle of every length", "has many cycles of evry length": is this the only difference which distingishes thid from other ?

Comment: @Agawa001 That's one difference, the other is that the other challenge is about functions on the positive integers, whereas this challenge asks for a function on all integers.

Comment: I think your definition of cycle needs to include that n is minimal. Otherwise, your cycle of length 2 also counts as your cycle of length 4 and 6 and so on.

Comment: @xnor Whoops, good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>27</s> 18 bytes

```
_h?gQ0^2Q*.5@,Q-xh
```

Explanation (Pyth initializes `Q` to the input integer):

```
_                       negative of (
                          (
  ?gQ0                      if Q >= 0:
      ^2Q                     2**Q
                            else:
         *.5                  half of
            @        Q          element Q (modulo list length) in
             ,                    the two element list [
              Q                     Q,
                 hQ                 ((Q plus 1)
                x  Q                 XOR Q)
               -    Q               minus Q
                                  ]
 h                        ) plus 1
                        )
```

This has cycles

(−1)
(0, −2)
(1, −3, −4)
(2, −5, −7, −6)
(3, −9, −13, −11, −8)
(4, −17, −25, −21, −15, −10)
(5, −33, −49, −41, −29, −19, −12)
(6, −65, −97, −81, −57, −37, −23, −14)
(7, −129, −193, −161, −113, −73, −45, −27, −16)
(8, −257, −385, −321, −225, −145, −89, −53, −31, −18)
(9, −513, −769, −641, −449, −289, −177, −105, −61, −35, −20)
⋮

The cycle of length *n* is given by

(*n* − 2,
−2^(*n* − 2)⋅1 − 1,
−2^(*n* − 3)⋅3 − 1,
−2^(*n* − 4)⋅5 − 1,
…,
−2^2⋅(2·*n* − 7) − 1,
−2^1⋅(2·*n* − 5) − 1,
−2^0⋅(2·*n* − 3) − 1).

Each integer *k* ≥ −1 appears as the first element of the (*k* + 2)-cycle.  For each integer *k* < −1, we can uniquely write 1 − *k* = 2^*i* ⋅ (2⋅*j* + 1) for some *i*, *j* ≥ 0; then *k* appears as the (*j* + 2)th element of the (*i* + *j* + 2)−cycle.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 47 bytes

```
E|G0<-QXJ:tQ*2/0hStJ<f0))Q2MQ)&:J6M-)2/ttk>Eq*k
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=RXxHMDwtUVhKOnRRKjIvMGhTdEo8ZjApKVEyTVEpJjpKNk0tKTIvdHRrPkVxKms&input=Mw)

#### General explanation

*Function 2 below is the same as used in [@Sp3000's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53648/36398) to the related challenge. Thanks to @Agawa001 for noticing.*

The function is the composition of three:

1. Bijection from **Z** (the integers) to **N** (the naturals).
2. Bijection from **N** to **N** with the desired characteristic (one cycle of each length).
3. Inverse of function 1.

Functions 1 and 3 are used because it's easier (I think) to achieve the desired behaviour in **N** than in **Z**.

Function 2 is as follows: upper line is domain, lower line is codomain. Commas are used for clarity:

```
1,  2  3,  4  5  6,  7  8  9  10  ...
1,  3  2,  6  4  5, 10  7  8   9  ...
```

The first block (from upper `1` to lower `1`) is a cycle of length 1. The second (from `2 3` to `3 2`) is a cycle of length 2, etc. In each block, the lower part (image of the function) is the upper part circularly shifted one step to the right.

Function 1 is as follows:

```
 -5  -4  -3  -2  -1   0  +1  +2  +3  +4  ...
+10  +8  +6  +4  +2  +1  +3  +5  +7  +9  ...
```

Function 3 is the same as 1 with the two lines swapped.

#### Examples

The image of `3` is `-5`. First `3` is mapped to `7` by function 1; then `7` is mapped to `10` by function 2; then `10` is mapped to -5` by function 3.

The length-1 cycle is `0`. The length-2 cycle is `-1 1`. The length-3 cycle is `-3 2 -2`, etc.

#### Code explained

Functions 1 and 3 are straightforward.

Function 2 works by finding the lower endpoint of the corresponding input block. For example, if the input to this function is `9` it finds `7` (see blocks above). It then picks the upper endpoint, which is `10` in the example. The circular shift of the block is achieved thanks to MATL's 1-based, modular indexing.

```
         % FUNCTION 1
         % Implicit input
E|       % Multiply by two. Absolute value
G0<      % 1 if input is negative, 0 otherwise
-        % Subtract
Q        % Add 1
XJ       % Copy to clipboard J. Used as input to the next function

         % FUNCTION 2
:        % Range [1 2 ... J], where J denotes the input to this function
tQ*      % Duplicate, increment by 1, multiply
2/       % Divide by 2
0hS      % Prepend a 0. This is needed in case J is 0
tJ<f     % Duplicate. Find indices that are less than the input J
0)       % Pick the last index.
)        % Apply as index to obtain input value that ends previous block
Q        % Add 1: start of current block
2M       % Push the two arguments to second-to-last function call
Q)       % Add 1 and use as index: end of current block
&:       % Inclusive binary range: generate input block 
J        % Push J (input to function 2)
6M-      % Subtract start of block
)        % Apply as index (1-based, modular). This realizes the shifting

         % FUNCTION 3
2/       % Divide by 2
ttk>     % Duplicate. 1 if decimal part is not 0; 0 otherwise
Eq       % Multiply by 2, add 1
*        % Multiply
k        % Round down
         % Implicit display
```

Comment: this is a twist of sp3000 s function right ?

Comment: @Agawa001 Oh is it? I didn't see the other challenge. I'll take a look

Comment: Oh. It definitely is. At least that clarifies that my reasoning, if not original, was correct :-)

Comment: it is surprising how more than one mind are closely framed to exude close ideas.

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2, 55 bytes

```python
g=lambda n,k=1:n/k and~g(~n+k*(n>0),k+1)+k*(n>0)or-~n%k
```

---

**59 bytes:**

```python
g=lambda n,k=1:n<0and~g(~n,2)or n/k and k+g(n-k,k+2)or-~n%k
```

Creates the cycles

```python
[0]
[-1, -2]
[1, 2, 3]
[-3, -4, -5, -6]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
...
```

Modified from [my solution on the earlier challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53668/20260), which is modified from [Sp3000's construction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53648/20260).

The function

```python
g=lambda n,k=1:n/k and k+g(n-k,k+2)or-~n%k
```

makes odd-size cycles of non-negative numbers

```python
[0]
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
...
```

To find the correct cycle size `k`, shift the input `n` down by `k=1,3,5,7,...` until the result is in the interval `[0,k)`. Cycle this interval with the operation `n->(n+1)%k`, then undo all the subtractions done on the input. This is implemented recursively by `k+g(n-k,k+2)`.

Now, we need the negative to make the even cycles. Note that if we modify `g` to start with `k=2` in `g`, we'd get even-size cycles

```python
[0, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
...
```

These biject to negatives via bit-complement `~`. So, when `n` is negative, we simply evaluate `g(n)` as `~g(~n,2)`.

Comment: I don't know whether it helps, but another way of calculating `k` seems to be `Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n))*2+1`.

Comment: @Neil I looked into determining the boundaries and cycle sizes arithmetically and even doing the whole computation that way, but these expressions are lengthy in Python and I found recursion to be shorter.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3,  146 bytes

For every number greater than 0, there are even loops (len 2,4,6,8...), and less than 0, odd loops (1,3,5,7). 0 maps to 0.

(-3,-2,-1),(0),(1,2),(3,4,5,6)

maps to

(-2,-1,-3),(0),(2,1),(6,3,4,5)

```
f=lambda x:1+2*int(abs(x)**.5)if x<1 else 2*int(x**.5+.5)
x=int(input());n=f(x)
if x>0:b=n*(n-2)/4
else:b=-((n+1)/2)**2
print(b+1+(x-b-2)%n)
```

Edit: @TuukkaX took off 8 bytes from the previous solution. And another 3.

Comment: I _think_ you can remove an whitespace before the if statement at the first line. And `mi` could be changed to something smaller, such as `b`.

Comment: Here is the same program golfed down: `f=lambda x:1+2*int(abs(x)**0.5)if x<1 else 2*int(x**0.5+0.5) x=int(input()) n=f(x) if x>0:b=n*(n-2)/4 else:b=-((n+1)/2)**2 print(b+1+(x-b-2)%n)`

Comment: Thanks, @TuukkaX . I forgot about the 2 character variable 'mi'.

Comment: I also changed `input('')` to `input()`. The quotes are useless since we don't have to print anything to the console when we want to just get the input.

Comment: Even shorter. Removed the zeroes before the dots. `f=lambda x:1+2*int(abs(x)**.5)if x<1 else 2*int(x**.5+.5)
x=int(input());n=f(x)
if x>0:b=n*(n-2)/4
else:b=-((n+1)/2)**2
print(b+1+(x-b-2)%n)`

Answer (score 2):

### Matlab(423)

```
function u=f(n),if(~n)u=n;else,x=abs(n);y=factor(x);for o=1:nnz(y),e=prod(nchoosek(y,o)',1);a=log(x)./log(e);b=find(a-fix(a)<exp(-9),1);if ~isempty(b),k=e(b);l=fix(a(b));break;end;end,if(abs(n)==1)k=2;l=0;end,if(k==2)l=l+1;x=x*2;end,e=dec2base(l,k)-48;o=xor(e,circshift(e,[0 1]));g=~o(end);if(~o|nnz(o==1)~=numel(e)-g),u=n*k;else,if((-1)^g==sign(n)),u=sign(n)*k^(base2dec([e(2:end-1) 1]+48,k)-(k==2));else,u=n*k;end,end,end
```

- Non-competing because it breaks a good record of being condidate for the last ranking, whilst I am struggling to shorten it as possible as i can.
- Some nonesensical bugs concerning accuracy in matlab that I couldnt find any way out except making my code sarcatistically big, in other hand the mapping I opt for was in terms of prime facors and n-ary logarithm.

**Execution**

```
 f(2)

 1

 f(1)

 2

 f(-2)

 -4

 f(-4)

 -8

 f(-8)

 -1

 f(0)

 0



 ----------------------------
```

### Explanation

- Knonwing, first off, that any number can be written as product of exponents of primes `N=e1^x1*e2^x2...` from this base i chose to map images of cycles `C` which are extracted from the biggest exponent of the smallest factor (not necessarily prime) that N is a perfect power of.
- in simpler words, let `N=P^x` where P is the smallest perfect root, `x` denotes precisely two essential terms for the cycle : `x=Ʃ(r*P^i)`, a term `P` is the base of cycle as well a perfect root for the main number N, and `k` is the degree of the cycle `C=p^k`, where `i` varies between 1 and k, the coeffecient `r` is incremented by 1 and bounded by P-1 for any following pre-image until all coeffecients are set to r=1, so we move to the start of that cycle.
- To avoid collisions between cycles the choice of exponentiation of primes rather than their products is accurate, because as an example of two cycles of bases `3` and `2` a meetpoint between them can be `3*2`, so this is avoided since a cycle is defined by its degree more than its base , and for the meetpoint there is another cycle of base `6` and degree 1.
- Negative numbers place an exception, as for it, i reserved odd degrees for negative numbers, and even degrees for the rest. How so ?

  for any number N embedded within a cycle `P^k`, is written as `P^(a0*P^i0+a1*P^i1+...)`, the amount `(a0*P^i0+a1*P^i1+...)` is transalted in P-ary base as `a0,a1,....` , to clarify this point if (p=2) the sequence must be in binary base. As is known prealably without setting the condition of positive/negative degrees and the (+/-1) exception, a number N is on the edges of a cycle of degree `k` if and only if the sequence `A` is written as `1111..{k+1}..10` or `111..{k}..1` for all bases, otherwise no rotation is needed, thus assigning negative/positive condition for a respective odd/even degrees `k/k'` for both makes an odd sequence written in the form `101..{k}..100`, an even sequence is written in the form `101..{k'}..10` for a beginning edge of a respectively negative/positive number-cycle.

  **Example:**

  Taking a number `N=2^10`, `x=10=2^1+2^3` , the sequence A is written `A=1010`, this type of sequence symptomizes a finite edge of positive number-cycle, which is `C=2^3`, so the next image is that of beginning edge `A=011` which is `8`, **But**, by standarizing this result to (+/-)1 exception `2^10/2` maps to `8/2` and the previous image mustnt be rotated.

  Taking a number `N=-3^9`, `x=9=3^2` , the sequence A is written `A=100`, this type of sequence symptomizes a finite edge of negative number-cycle, which is `C=3^1`, so the next image is that of beginning edge `A=01` which is `3`, But, by adapting this result to negative/positive condition `-3^9` maps to `-3` .
- for the couple `(-/+)1`, i envisaged to intrude it within numbers of cycle-bases `2`, in a guise that an ordinary sequence of cyclic groups `{2,4}{8,16,32,64}..` are made up in another form `{1,2}{4,8,16,32}..`, this prevents any loss of previous elements, and the opeation done is just shifting with popping a new element in.

---

**Results:**

running this little code-sheet to verify the first reasonable ranges of cyclic numbers:

```
for (i=1:6) 
index=1;if(max(factor(i))>=5) index=0;end
for ind=0:index
j=f(((-1)^ind)*i); while(((-1)^ind)*i~=j)fprintf('%d ',j);j=f(j);end,fprintf('%d \n',(-1)^ind*i),pause,end,
end
```

This leads to this results

```
 2 1 
 -2 -4 -8 -1 
 1 2 
 -4 -8 -1 -2 
 9 27 3 
 -9 -27 -81 -243 -729 -2187 -6561 -19683 -3 
 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 4 
 -8 -1 -2 -4 
 25 125 625 3125 5 
 36 216 1296 7776 46656 6 
 -36 -216 -1296 -7776 -46656 -279936 -1679616 -10077696 -60466176 -362797056 -2.176782e+009 -1.306069e+010 ??? Error using ==> factor at 27
```

The last one is segmentation-error but it fits the [-127,127] standard signed-integer range.

Comment: I used this technique awhile ago to define hash functions in an old C program of mine, it works neat !

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, 110 bytes

*I still have not figured out how to get a lambda in there*

if n is a triangle number [1,3,6,10,15,21,28,etc...] then f(n) is the order in the list multiplied by negative one. if the number is negative, give it 1+the next smallest triangle number. else, increment.

Example: 5 is not a triangle number, so add 1.

Next iteration, we have 6. 6 is a triangle number, and it is the 3rd in the list, so out comes -3.

The program gives these lists

length 1:[0]

length 2:[1,-1]

length 3:[2,3,-2]

length 4:[4,5,6,-3]

length 5:[7,8,9,10,-4]

```
x=int(input())
if x<0:print((x**2+x)/2+1)
else:
 a=((8*x+1)**.5-1)/2
 if a%1:print(x+1)
 else:print(-a)
```

Edit: Thanks again to @TuukkaX for removing excess charcters.

Comment: You could change `0.5` to `.5` and `input('')` to `input()`.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 73 bytes

```
f=(n,i=0,j=0,k=0,l=1,m=i<0?-i:~i)=>n-i?f(n,m,k++?j:i,k%=l,l+!k):++k-l?m:j
```

Works by enumerating the sequence (0, -1, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, ...) until it finds `n`, counting cycles as it goes. `i` contains the current entry; `j` contains the start of the current cycle, `k` the index within the cycle, `l` the length of the current cycle and `m` the next entry in the sequence. Once we find `n` we then take `j` if we're at the end of a cycle or `m` if not.